# ng-repeat: How to set property multiple in select

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have  object (arr) when repeat, he have property `charType`: `select` or `multiple`.

I want if `charType` is `"select"` see  normal select, but if `charType` is `"multiple"` see select with multiple.

Example:

If  object (arr) have 5 result 0,1,2 is `charType` 'select' and 3,4 `charType` is  'multiple'.I want to see 
0 select
1 select
2 select
3 select with multiple
4 select with multiple

```html
<div class="form-group" ng-repeat="att in arr track by $index">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <label for="phone" ng-model="type">{{att.name}}</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-9">
    ({{att.charType}})
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="charObj.charactValue[att.businessassetID + $index]" ng-if="att.charType == 'select' ? 'multiple' : 'multiple=true'">
      <option ng-repeat="itemss in att.value track by $index" value="{{itemss}}">{{itemss}}</option>
    </select>
    <div class="text-center"><a class="insertStore" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addCharacteristicValue" ng-click="getObj(att)">Добави</a>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try `ng-if="{{att.charType}} == ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working snippet :

- Use ng-options instead of ng-repeat in option tag
- Remove track by index make select fail
- Use a simple ng-if to generate two differents select.

There isn't `ng-multiple` directive it seems, so i went for the `ng-if` workaround.

```js
angular.module("app", []).controller("ctrl", function($scope){
    $scope.arr = [{charType:'select', name:'select', value:[1, 2]},{charType:'multiple', name:'multiple', value:[1,2]}]; 
    $scope.charObj = {characterValue:{}};
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>



<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="att in arr track by $index">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <label for="phone" ng-model="type">{{att.name}}</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-9">
        ({{att.charType}})
        <select ng-if="att.charType == 'select'" class="form-control" ng-model="charObj.charactValue[att.businessassetID + $index]"  ng-options="itemss for itemss in att.value">
        </select>
                <select ng-if="att.charType != 'select'" multiple class="form-control" ng-model="charObj.charactValue[att.businessassetID + $index]"  ng-options="itemss for itemss in att.value">
        </select>
      
      </div>
    </div>
    selected : {{charObj.charactValue}} <br />
</div>
```